# how to print a whole row from an array?

Tags: c++

I wrote a program which shows the data about 5 students I want to know how to show the  student name registration number and marks who obtained highest marks in the array.
The program is like that:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

struct student
{
    char name[30];
    char reg[10];
    short int marks_dbms;
    short int marks_prog;
};

void main()
{
    short int i;

    student a[5]={      
        {"salman","B-1499",92,98},
        {"Haider","B-1489",34,87},
        {"zeeshan","B-1897",87,90},
        {"faizan","B-1237",56,66},
        {"Asif","B-1233",88,83}

    };

    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\t",a[i].name);
        printf("%s\t",a[i].reg);
        printf("%d\t",a[i].marks_dbms);
        printf("%d\t\n",a[i].marks_prog);

    }

    getch();

}
```

Comment: I wonder who teaches people to indent by randomising.

Comment: it's `int main()` not `void main()`

Comment: reinderien i wana print the student's name registration num and marks who obtained the highest marks among all 5 students how to do that any one knows.

Comment: thanks Sam Miller for the correction but what about the main question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats a simple one.

```
int maxDbmsMarks = 0; 
int maxMarksIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   if(a[i].marks_dbms > maxDbmsMarks )
   {
        maxDbmsMarks = a[i].marks_dbms;
        maxMarksIndex = i;
   }
}

printf("Student with the maximum dbms marks :\n");
printf("Name : %s, Reg : %s, dbmsMarks: %d, progMarks : %d\n", a[maxMarksIndex].name, a[maxMarksIndex].reg, a[maxMarksIndex].makrs_dbms, a[maxMarksIndex].marks_prog);
```

It is the same as finding the maximum number in an array. The above logic is for 'highest dbms marks', you can modify it to find the highest prog marks or highest combined marks.

Comment: 2 days ago I answered a homework question with the code and got a ton of downvotes... ;(

Comment: @BlackBear: Eh. Let them downvote, it's 2 measly points.  I myself see the homework tag as completely irrelevant and so ignore it.  Of course others disagree, and I've read their arguments.  But I will continue to answer valid programming questions, regardless of the homework tag, and I will continue to get the downvotes.  If someone cheats their way through University and gets a job through it, it's the company's problem for relying on that University as a recruiting tool, and the University's problem for not properly testing their students' knowledge before graduating them.  Not my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, write a function to compare students by their marks.  It should accept two student parameters, and return true if the first student should be considered less than the second.

```
bool compareStudentsByMarks(const student & lhs, const student & rhs)
{
    // This only compares by marks_dbms, I'm not sure how you want to do it.
    return lhs.marks_dbms < rhs.marks_dbms;
}
```

Then, after including the `<algorithm>` header, use the function `std::max_element`, passing your function as the last argument.

```
const int SIZE_OF_STUDENT_ARRAY = 5;
student * pmax = std::max_element(a, a+SIZE_OF_STUDENT_ARRAY, compareStudentsByMarks);
// now pmax is a pointer to the student with the highest marks,
// you already know how to display their info
```

If you have access to C++0x, this is all a lot easier:

```
auto pmax = std::max_element(a, a+SIZE_OF_STUDENT_ARRAY,
    [](const student & lhs, const student & rhs)
    {
        return lhs.marks_dbms < rhs.marks_dbms;
    });
```